# Why override equals instead of using another method name

Tags: java

This seems like a silly question but why do we override `equals` method instead of creating a new method with new name and compare using it?

If I didn't override equals that means both `==` and equals check whether both references are pointed to same memory location?

Comment: What about Data structures which use the *available* `equals()` method?. Example Map, Set?

Comment: You can also implement `toString()` with a different name. But then no other code (except your own) is going to make use of it.

Comment: BTW, I don't think it's a silly question.  I think it's important to understanding the Java object model.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> This seems like a silly question but why do we override `equals` method instead of creating a new method with new name and compare using it?

Because all standard collections (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, `HashMap`, ...) use `equals` when deciding if two objects are equal.

If you invent a new method these collections wouldn't know about it and not work as intended.

The following is very important to understand: If a collection such as `ArrayList` calls `Object.equals` this call will, in runtime, resolve to the overridden method. So even though you invent classes that the collections are not aware of, they can still invoke methods, such as `equals`, on those classes.

> If I didn't override equals that means both `==` and equals check whether both references are pointed to same memory location?

Yes. The implementation of `Object.equals` just performs a `==` check.

Comment: One last thing. If i made two Strings like this //String a = "Hello"; String b = "Hello"; that means both a and b references are pointed to the same object? So i can use equals() to compare them anytime without overriding it?

Comment: [Strings are special](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) in Java. If you do `String a = "Hello"; String b = "Hello";` then  `== ` will work.

Comment: Got it, that is why == can not be used to compare two String contents :)

Comment: Right. In general you can't use == when comparing Strings :-) (It *might* work if you have compile time constants.) In general Strings are bad to use as example when explaining / thinking about equals vs ==.

Answer (score 9):

You override equals if you are using classes that rely on equals, such as `HashMap`, `HashSet`, `ArrayList` etc...

For example, if you store elements of your class in a `HashSet`, you must override `hashCode` and `equals` if you want the uniqueness of elements to be determined not by simple reference equality.

Yes, if you don't override equals, the default equals implementation (as implemented in the `Object` class) is the same as `==`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the main reason, already given in other answers, consider program readability.

If you override `equals` and `hashCode` anyone reading your code knows what the methods are for. Doing so tells the reader the criteria for value equality between instances of your class. Someone reading your code that uses `equals` will immediately know you are checking for value equality.

If you use some other name, it will only confuse readers and cost them extra time reading your JavaDocs to find out what your method is for.

Answer (score 4):

Because `equals()` is a method of the `Object` class, which is the superclass of all classes, and due to which it is inherently present in every class you write. Hence every collection class or other standard classes use `equals()` for object comparsion. If you want your custom class objects to be supported for equality by other classes, you have to override `equals()` only (since other classes know that for object comparion call `equals()`). If you are only using your own classes, you might create a new method and make sure everything uses your custom method for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The equals and hashcode method are special methods, widely used across the java's utility classes specially collection framework, and the wrpper classes e.g. String, Integer have overridden this method, So e.g. if you are placing any Object of your choice which has correct equals and hashcode implementation inside the HashSet, to maintain the property of uniqueness the hashcode will compare with all the existing object in hashset, and if it finds any of the hashcode matching then it looks into the equals method to double check if both are really equal and if that equality check also is pass then incoming object is rejected, but if the hashcode equality check is not passed then hashset will not go for the equals method and straight way place that object into the hashset. So we need to make sure the implementation of equals and hashcode is logically proper.

Answer (score 2):

A class like `HashMap<T,U>` needs to have some means of identifying which item in the collection, if any, should be considered equivalent to a given item.  There are two general means via which this can be accomplished:

1. Requiring that anything to be stored in a collection must include virtual methods to perform such comparison (and preferably provide a quick means (e.g. `hashCode()`) of assigning partial equivalence classes).
2. Require that code which creates the collection must supply an object which can accept references to other objects and perform equivalence-related operations upon them.

It would have been possible to omit `equals` and `hashCode()` from `Object`, and have types like `HashMap` only be usable with key types that implement an `equatable` interface that includes such members; code which wishes to use collections of references keyed by identity would have to use `IdentityHashMap` instead.  Such a design would not have been unreasonable, but the present design makes it possible for a general-purpose collection-of-collections type which uses `HashMap` to be usable with things that are compared by value as well as by identity, rather than having to define a separate types for collection-of-HashMap and collection-of-IdentityHashMap.

An alternative design might have been to have a `GeneralHashMap` type whose constructor requires specifying a comparison function, and have `IdentityHashMap` and `HashMap` both derive from that; the latter would constrain its type to `equatable` and have its identity functions chain to those of the objects contained therein.  There would probably have been nothing particularly wrong with that design, but that's not how things were done.

In any case, there needs to be some standard means by which collections can identify items that should be considered equivalent; using virtual `equals(Object)` and `getHashCode()` is a way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1

There are Two things. 
`equals()` is Located inside Object class
Collection framework using `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods when comparing objects

> Question 2

Yes for comparing two Object. but when You comparing two String Objects using `equals()` its only checking the value.